# Generate class from code visual studio

Tags: class, generator

Is there a way I can generate a class based on existing code on my application?

That is, I have code I written not using classes and I would like to incorporate that into my project.

I can do it manually but I was wondering if there was a function such as refractor in Visyal Studio that I could use to select a bound of code and translate it into a Class.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Let's suppose:

```
    FolderBrowserDialog directorio = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    directorio.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    directorio.SelectedPath = @"C:\TRACKER\DICOM";
    directorio.Description = "Select a directory with Dicom Images";


    if (directorio.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path_directorio_imagenes = directorio.SelectedPath;
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path_directorio_imagenes).GetFiles();

        if (fileInfo.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The directory doesn't contains any file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }

        int nro_archivos = fileInfo.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < nro_archivos; ++i)
        {
            string archivo = fileInfo[i].FullName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(archivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII);
            byte[] preamble = new byte[132];
            br.Read(preamble, 0, 132);
            if (preamble[128] != 'D' || preamble[129] != 'I' || preamble[130] != 'C' || preamble[131] != 'M')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The directory contains a file that's not a DICOM file");
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do as I'm having a tough time understanding your question.

Comment: I just added some code to my original post.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do with that code. You say your code is written not using classes, but in .NET/C# that's not possible, EVERY method has to be in a class, there's no other way to do it. So what I'm looking at above is a method (or part of a method) that must be part of a class.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, the code above is in the Main() and I would like to create a class to handle that functionality for example

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see what the confusion is, just create a class and move the code into it. See below (I can't do it here because of the limited formatting capabilities of comments).

Answer (score 1):

Just take the code an put it in a method of a new class...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog directorio = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        directorio.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        directorio.SelectedPath = @"C:\TRACKER\DICOM";
        directorio.Description = "Select a directory with Dicom Images";

        if (directorio.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path_directorio_imagenes = directorio.SelectedPath;
            FileInfo[] fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path_directorio_imagenes).GetFiles();

            if (fileInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The directory doesn't contains any file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }

            int nro_archivos = fileInfo.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < nro_archivos; ++i)
            {
                string archivo = fileInfo[i].FullName;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(archivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII);
                byte[] preamble = new byte[132];
                br.Read(preamble, 0, 132);
                if (preamble[128] != 'D' || preamble[129] != 'I' || preamble[130] != 'C' || preamble[131] != 'M')
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The directory contains a file that's not a DICOM file");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you need to use it.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
bool result = myClass.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be that easy. Now, if you look at my code, there's a line which displays a MesssageBox, will that work if I do what you suggest?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? That's the best way to learn stuff, try it, see what happens, and then ask questions if you don't understand the results.